# Save Integer to compare with random number

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I have created a method to generate a random number and update a label with the generated number.

```
- (void)generateNumber {

int i = arc4random() % 100;

NSLog(@"Random Number: %i", i);
NSString *randomNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
self.myLabel.text = randomNumber;}
```

Now I wish to save that number in order to compare the old generated number with the new one, inside this method:

```
- (IBAction)downButton {

[self generateNumber];

//And do something like
if(newNumber > oldNumber){
     NSLog(@"Number is lower: %i", i); }}
```

Any help how to do this please?

Comment: save it (and the new one) in a property

Comment: I am a beginner, can you provide me with an example please?

Comment: you learn by doing, not copying. first define the properties, then update them, then log them, then use them for calculating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property for the generated number and let your method return the new generated number.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger generatedInt;
```

Maybe you should initialise your property "generatedInt" ;)

```
- (NSInteger)generateNumber { ... return i; }
```

And then in your downButton method compare these two values:

```
    - (IBAction)downButton {
    NSInteger newNumber = [self generateNumber];

    if(newNumber < self.generatedInt){
        NSLog(@"Number is lower: %i", i);
    }
    self.generatedInt = newNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try both approaches

Answer (score 0):

**globaly declare:**

```
int oldNumber =100;
```

then edit this

```
- (IBAction)downButton {
  int newNumber = [self generateNumber];

   //And do something like
   if(newNumber > oldNumber){
    NSLog(@"Number is lower: %i", newNumber);
   }
  oldNumber = newNumber;
}

- (int)generateNumber {

 int i = arc4random() % 100;

 NSLog(@"Random Number: %i", i);
 NSString *randomNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
 //self.myLabel.text = randomNumber;
 return i;
}
```

Comment: in case of first random number  you have no value so you shuld handle this.

Comment: i provided you a complete solution by testing, so you can check

Comment: welcome. if you accept the correct answer, it will help to find the someone the correct one.